# F# - Using List.foldBack to concatenate a list to itself

Tags: list, f#, concatenation

How do you use List.foldBack to concatenate a list to itself?

For example, if the input list to the function was: [10; 20; 30; 40] Then the output would be: [10; 20; 30; 40; 10; 20; 30; 40]

Is there a way to do this any number of times and to be able to specify the number of times for the list to concatenate itself to itself? For example, three times would be: [10; 20; 30; 40; 10; 20; 30; 40; 10; 20; 30; 40]

Answer (score 4):

The `foldBack` function keeps a state and applies a function iteratively on the current state and all elements of a given list. In your case, you want to keep some list as the state and append elements to it in the right way while you are iterating over the input.

The following will just recreate the same list as it was:

```
let list = [ 10; 20; 30 ]
let init = [] 
List.foldBack (fun x xs -> x::xs) init list
```

This starts with `[]`, gradually appending elements from the end to this, so you get `[30]`, then `[20; 30]` and then `[10; 20; 30]`.

This should give you enough background to figure out what you need:

- To get a list appended to itself, you'll need to choose the right `init` state, so that you're not starting with an empty list.
- To do this repeatedly a given number of times, you'll just need to do this multiple times using recursion

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to work on this more later today. I was actually hoping for an answer like this and not just full on code to copy/paste, as this is an assignment and I'm not trying to cheat. I'm just stuck on this part of the assignment and needed to better understand what to do.  The code that you did write, was pretty close to what I had already figured out for myself, but the explanation should help me finish.